# How to get percentage of male/female followers in twitter api in php?

Tags: twitter

i need to get percentage of  male/female followers in twitter using twitter API. I am able to get total followers but not able to get percentage of  male/female followers.

```
$obj = new TwitterOAuth($keys['AppKey'], $keys['SecretKey'],$sKey2,$sKey3);
$detail = $obj->get('account/verify_credentials');
$return=$return+$detail->followers_count;
```

**How to get male/female followers in twitter using api?**

Answer (score 0):

The [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation) does not give access to a gender split.

There are two possible ways you can find it.

1. Scrape the http://analytics.twitter.com/ website - that displays follower gender split.
2. Analyse the photos & names of the followers and attempt to determine gender from that.